# React setState re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I'm really new into React, so forgive my lack of knowledge about the subject.

As far as I know, when you setState a new value, it renders again the view (or parts of it that needs re-render).

I've got something like this, and I would like to know if it's a good practice or not, how could I solve this kind of issues to improve, etc.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            key: value
        }
        this.functionRender = this.functionRender.bind(this)
        this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this)
    }
    functionRender = () => {
        if(someParams !== null) {
            return <AnotherComponent param={this.state.key} />
        }
        else {
            return "<span>Loading</span>"
        }
    }
    changeValue = (newValue) => {
        this.setState({
            key: newValue
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>... {this.functionRender()} ... <span onClick={() => this.changeValue(otherValue)}>Click me</span></div>)
    }
}
```

**Another component**

```
class AnotherComponent extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render () {
        return (
            if (this.props.param === someOptions) {
                return <div>Options 1</div>
            } else {
                return <div>Options 2</div>
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The intention of the code is that when I click on the span it will change the key of the state, and then the component `<AnotherComponent />` should change because of its parameter.

I assured that when I make the setState, on the callback I throw a console log with the new value, and it's setted correctly, but the `AnotherComponent` doesn't updates, because depending on the param given it shows one thing or another.

Maybe I need to use some lifecycle of the MyComponent?

**Edit**

I found that the `param` that `AnotherComponent` is receiving it does not changes, it's always the same one.

Comment: I might be misreading this, but shouldn't this be `this.functionRender()`?

Comment: you don't need to `bind` the functions in the constructor if you're using arrow functions

Comment: Totally true, I didn't copied it well! but question still remains!

Comment: thanks for the advice @Yoav didn't know that!

Comment: it would be helpful if you'll show the `<AnotherComponent/>` implementation

Comment: Your code works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/5xzlrm61v4

Comment: @Cheshire I should have also mentioned, that ought to fix your problem; did you try it?

Comment: in my code i got that @OliverRadini just didn't copied it here.

Comment: @Yoav give me a minute or two to add it here!

Comment: @Yoav the other component is added.

Comment: @Yoav I found that in the AnotherComponent the param that is receiving it's always the same, it doesn't changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you'll first test it in the parent using a simple `console.log` on your `changeValue` function:

```
changeValue = (newValue) => {
    console.log('newValue before', newValue);
    this.setState({
        key: newValue
    }, ()=> console.log('newValue after', this.state.key))
}
```

`setState` can accept a [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that will be invoked after the state actually changed (remember that `setState` [is async)](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Since we can't see the entire component it's hard to understand what actually goes on there.
I suspect that the `newValue` parameter is always the same but i can't be sure.
It seems like you're missing the `props` in `AnotherComponent`'s constructor. it should be:

```
 constructor (props) {
    super(props) // here
}
```

Try replacing the if statement with:

```
{this.props.param === someOptions? <div>Options 1</div>: <div>Options 2</div>}
```

also add this function to see if the new props actually get to the component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    console.log(newProps);
}
```

and check for the type of `param` and `someOptions` since you're (rightfully) using the `===` comparison.

Comment: I tried that, and it changes the value of the state with the `newValue`. What I have is a tab selection with 3 options, and some "movements" on someones account. I can retrieve with that exact same function the tab value, but it won't change on the parameter to give it to the other component and render different movements. I really appreciate your time trying to help!

Comment: In my actual code I got props in both, constructor and super, I updated the code

Comment: Thanks! The componentWillReceiveProps did work. Without it, the state was not changing, while the props was. I had to update the state with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, fat arrow ( `=>` ) autobind methods so you do not need to bind it in the constructor, second re-renders occur if you change the key of the component.

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: What I've found, in the AnotherComponent, the param it's always the same, it's not changing

Comment: It doesn't *autobind*, it runs in the current lexical scope.

Comment: @DavinTryon you are correct, fat arrows don't create their own this reference but keep the reference of the context. "Autobind" was intended as "does not need to be bound"